# has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop

I have an error from my database.  Below is my error.  How can i solve this problem, and why did I have it?

> #### Error:
>
> SQL query:
>
> `SET NAMES utf8;`
>
> #### MySQL said:
>
> #1226 - User 'db' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 75000)

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: You've not given us anything to go on. What is 'max_questions' - how is it defined? Where is this limit set? Is this a database you created, or does it belong to something else? Why did you tag this question with 'ppp' - what does the point-to-point protocol (used for modems, mostly) have to do with your database?

Comment: im asking about what is max_question , i dont have it on my data base and it gives error for max_question , yes , its my database i'v created it , sorry i tagged it wrong , i mean oop, what i have to do with my database to solve this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Your host has placed a limit of 75,000 SQL queries per hour. Contact your host, or if you manage the database server yourself, adjust the value in the MySQL configuration.

```
update user set max_questions = 0 where user = 'db';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-resources.html

Comment: i know what you mean , but my problem is my database dont contain so many users for requiring this error ,what is the main reason for this error ?

Comment: @ahmadgarmyani The reason for this error is that more than 75,000 queries were made against the database for the user `db` in one hour. You'll want to benchmark your code and see what's causing so many queries.

Comment: ive used the same database in other place (webmobile) and it doesn't have any problems.

Comment: @ahmadgarmyani "Webmobile" isn't a database. You're using the MySQL database. Other web hosts may not have the same 75k query limitations this host has.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  It is possible it happened to me because I made a couple of backups as well some big queries before and after the backups to verify that the database was in reasonable shape.

My solution: I created a new database user that I will use in the future for admin purposes (aka database backups).  This user is different from that which is used by PHP running on my website.  Now, if I exceed the limit when logged into the database as the admin user, the website that the public sees will not be affected.